# Edit Hide Settings in Bootstrap Popup Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap hide model in my page with FORM on it. it display when page is Load. 
what i want to do is it should be disappear only if form is submitted. but the problem is when visitor click 'X' button in the Top right or Click background outside the model it gets disappear. how to edit the plugin according to that? or is there any other easy Popup plugins to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use two attributes: backdrop and keyboard, explained in detail [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options).

So an example code would be:

```
$('#theModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

You could also set this attributes in your html like:

```
<a href="#" data-controls-modal="theModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

Comment: Dangit beat me to it. for a complete example, see [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Bn487YUwbc) @PatrickLC -feel free to fork it and add to your answer